# Converting an excel tab to a CSV file is casting my columns into floats. Need to change to String

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

So I have been reading through the documentation for both [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and I can seem to figure this one out. What I'm doing is taking a Excel workbook and converting one of the tabs into a csv. Then, with said CSV, preforming some ETL.

My issue is, in the final CSV, I have a column that is a mix of numbers and strings.
And my issue is that, in excel it looks fine but in notepad++ you can see the floating points being added. I need this column to remain as strings.

In my ETL code I have casted this column to a string, but all that does is it turns the floats from excel to csv conversion, and transforms them into strings but still with the .0 added.

[image]

Code for cast to string in ETL

```
df['Old Serial Number'] = df['Old Serial Number'].astype(str)#Old Serial Number is the column with a mix of strings and INT'S (see notepad++ image)
```

Is there away that I can cast columns as strings at the point of the CSV creation so i can drop the floats?

This is the code I'm using for the conversion.

```
import openpyxl
import csv
import glob
import datetime
import shutil
import time
import logging

def convert_to_csv():
for filename in glob.glob(
        r"C:\Users\excel_file_that_i_want*"):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    sh = wb['Report']#excel tab i want from the workbook

    with open('excel_file_that_i_want' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d%m%Y%H%M%S''.csv'), 'w', encoding='utf-8',
              newline="") as f:
        col = csv.writer(f,
                         quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in sh.rows:
            col.writerow([cell.value for cell in row])
logging.info('Excel file converted to CSV')
```

Comment: Why not convert to ints? All values in CSV are **always** strings.

Comment: That could work as well, so long as it gets rid of my floats. How would i go about doing that in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because openpyxl interprets the value of the Excel cell from its type.

You can quickly pypass this with:

```
col.writerow([str(cell.value) for cell in row])
```

Comment: That makes sense but is this solution only applicable to each cell and not a whole Colum? I'm dealing with quite a bit of data, so induvial cell wouldn't work.

Comment: Using the following code that was suggested, the CSV returned as blank?

Comment: Which is your version of python and openpyxl? I can't reproduce it with mine.

Comment: Python 3.7 and im using openpyxl 3.0.7

Comment: Same version of openpyxl. Can you share an exemple of xlsx file?

Comment: Sure thing, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fd0wQRa6gmn00_1-OX11f0oAEz4ZDwlIvXrsyXSQ8AI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce... With this file its good for me